# How to tell where user account is logged in

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

In a windows 2003/2008 mixed domain, is it possible to find out where on the network a particular account is logged into?

The account keeps getting locked out, and we think the account may be logged in somewhere, but we don't know where.

Comment: Couldn't you just look at the client information in the lockout events?  Coming up with "where are all the places this account is in use" is incredibly difficult, but "what system is locking this account" is very easy.

Comment: FYI: I figured what was locking my account.  We use a tool called mRemote to manage multiple RDP sessions.  When you create a profile for a machine, if you don't put in a password, it will try to pass in a null password when attempting to log in.  Try to log into 3 servers and bang, my account was locked.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you want the Account Lockout tools

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18465

Allows you to run a query against a domain controller's security logs to search for particular users - for example, to show where the failure audits are coming from.

Comment: I'm going to try this as soon as I get into work on Monday!  Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  The instructions state that you need to install ALockout.dll on the computer that generated the lockout error message.  How do I determine that?

Comment: Err I don't think you do. I've always just run it from my PC, against a domain controller. Just run EventCombMT and put the username as the search string

Comment: I found that logs on the DC and it says the source is my own computer.  I added the ALockout.dl for xp, but the logs are 0 kb. I think that it's because I'm using xp 64 bit.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer because these are obviously the right tools.  Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in about this.  I cannot tell you how much this has come in handy for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPing tool.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/uping/
It collects information about users logons to database (just put uping.exe to startup script).
And after that you can query the database jussk like ping: uping

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted, you can store the current logged in user and write it to AD. This would allow you to easily search for it in the future. Here is a short guide:

http://deployhappiness.com/find-out-what-computer-a-user-logged-into/